# A Donut inside another

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

I want to show two donuts charts in plotly for javascript, one inside another (just like the code bellow).

**The question is:** how to resize the inner pie to be inside the outer one?

```js
var data = [{
  values: [51,49],
  labels: ["Type 1","Type 2"],
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Control',
  marker: {
    colors: ['rgba(100, 100, 255, 0.7)','rgba(100, 100, 255, 1)'],
    line: {color: '#000000',width: 2}
  }  
},{
  values: [55,45],
  labels: ["Type 3","Type 4"],
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Control',
  hole: 0.8,
  marker: {
    colors: ['rgba(100, 200, 102, 0.7)','rgba(100, 200, 102, 1)'],
    line: {color: '#000000',width: 2}
  }  
}];

var layout = {
  height: 400,
  width: 480
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by resize. Do you want the ability to change its size to smaller or bigger ?

Comment: I would like that inner donut and outer donut hole have same size.

Comment: You mean overlapping each other. Is that what you want, then I think only one pie will be visible. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, the inner will be inside the outer one. Have you run the code? Click in "run code snippet" please.

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create it as a subplot and use `domain`:

```
var data = [{
  values: [51,49],
  labels: ["Type 1","Type 2"],
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Control',
  domain: {
    x: [0.2, .8],
    y: [0, 1]
  },
  marker: {
    colors: ['rgba(100, 100, 255, 0.7)','rgba(100, 100, 255, 1)'],
    line: {color: '#000000',width: 2}
  }  
},{
  values: [55,45],
  labels: ["Type 3","Type 4"],
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Control',
  hole: 0.8,
  marker: {
    colors: ['rgba(100, 200, 102, 0.7)','rgba(100, 200, 102, 1)'],
    line: {color: '#000000',width: 2}
  }  
}];

var layout = {
  height: 400,
  width: 480
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```